# Should you be able to vote for your own tag synonym proposals?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, tag-synonyms

You seem to be able to vote for your own tag synonym proposals.

Is this a bug or by design?

(My proposal [noframework/no-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=no-framework&sort=info&pagesize=50) that I voted on)

Comment: It makes sense that if you suggest it, it makes sense that it would have at least one vote to indicate your support for it.  It's not like you gain rep from synonym upvotes or anything.

Comment: @Andy I think it's implied that it has your support if you proposed it in the first place. I support all the questions, answers, and comments I post, but I'm not allowed to upvote them

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: yes, but you gain rep on those (with the exception of comments).  Also, barring special circumstances, all of those can be deleted if you change your mind.  Final argument, you don't actually own the tag synonym, it's not really "yours".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not by design and should not be allowed. I think there was a miscommunication on our team here.

Comment: Sorry waffles. I hope I haven't got you into trouble with the big boss man. =:)

Comment: no worries, just a miscommunication